# Exiting FindMinimum when a condition is met

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to determine if a function `f[x]` can take negative values. `f` is expensive to compute and `x` may be high-dimensional.

I thought to use `FindMinimum` to minimize with respect to `x`. If the minimum is positive I have an answer.

But I do not want to proceed with the costly minimization if, en route, an evaluation of `f` produces a negative value. 
I want to return to the calling program with the information:

> `f` can achieve a negative value.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 15


Catch[FindMinimum[f[x], x, StepMonitor :> 
   If[Negative@f@x, 
   Throw[Print@"func can achieve a negative value"]]]]
```

> `func can achieve a negative value`

Otherwise, it evaluates:

```
ff[x_]:=x^2+2

Catch[FindMinimum[ff[x], x, StepMonitor :> 
   If[Negative@ff@x, 
   Throw[Print@"func can achieve a negative value"]]]]
```

> `{2., {x -> 0.}}`

To wrap it in a function:

```
posFindMinimum[func_, args_?ListQ] :=
  Catch@FindMinimum[func @@ args, args, 
  StepMonitor :> 
  If[Negative@(func @@ args), 
  Throw[ToString@func <> " can achieve a negative value"]]]

posFindMinimum[f,{x}]
```

> `f can achieve a negative value`

Comment: This works for me. Thanks.